# building flexible GUI

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, runtime

I have a Layout that I want to populate with items consisting of 2 textviews and one button. I do not know before hand how many items that will populate my Layout. 
Since I don't know when writing the layout.xml how many items I want to add, thats means that I have to add the items in the java instead of the xml. But I do not like to build GUI in java because it looks ugly.

Does anyone know if I can create an xml file for my item and then add new items to my layout during execution?

I have written some pseudo code to try to demonstrate what I want to accomplish:

MainLayout.xml

```
//My empty Layout
<Layout myMainLayout >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment_post.xml

```
//one post
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<Button/>
```

In the code somewhere

```
setContentView(R.layout.MainLayout);
MyMainLayout.addFragment(R.layout.Fragment_post);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your fragment_post.xml wherever you want:

```
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout view=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourfragment, null);
yourLayout.addView(view);
```

Please don't confuse a Fragment with a piece of the GUI. See here for details: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do this. Just set an initial empty layout to your activity.

```
onCreate()
{
setContentView(R.layout.initial_layout);
}
```

Then get and keep a reference to main layout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout mainLayout=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.initial_layout, null);
```

Next, add  new views to your layout as and when you need them.

```
LinearLayout view=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, null);
mainLayout.addView(view);
```

But note that what you refer to as fragments here are not what android refers to as fragments. Learn about actual android fragments here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html